# Number of solutions to an equation with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions does $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = \frac{6(10^{100}-1)}{9}$$ have when each $x_i$ is a hunderd-digits positive integer made of only $1's$ and $2's$

I got an hint/instruction to first find the decimal representation of $\frac{6(10^{100}-1)}{9}$ which is of course the $100$-digits number $6.66...*10^{99}$

but I have no idea what to do next.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Hint: start with some simpler cases:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 6$
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 66$
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 666$

where the $x_i$ are $1, 2$ and $3$ digit numbers respectively. Do you notice anything? Can you generalise this?

Comment: Not quite. You're correct that the first equation has 6 solutions. For the second case, you can choose any two of the solutions from the first case and "put them together" to get a solution for the second case. For example, I can put together 1,1,2,2 and 2,2,1,1 to get 12, 12, 21, 21. Since there are 6 choices to choose from, this gives me a total of $6 \times 6 = 36$ choices for the second case.